# How to send and retrieve data of intent to its adapter class

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am a beginner in android studio, so please bear with me.

I've retrieved data from my intent in a recyclerview activity but I don't know how to pass it to its corresponding adapter class (`recyclerview_adapter.java`).

How should I start, does anybody have an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share some code. Activity/fragment , adapterClass

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just create a constructor inside adapter class with variable you want to pass and place a global variable by which you can use that variable(data).

```
class adapter{

     // you can pass whole object or any kind of data here as well, just replace string with appropriate class name...
     private String data;

     // the data string will be set from your recycle activity...
     public adapter(String data){
         this.data = data;
     }

     // use the data string anywhere in adapter class...

}
```